# Where is it written that anger is like idolatry

Tags: talmud-gemara, avodah-zarah, middos-character-traits

There is a gemara that says that anger is like a form of idolatry. Which gemara says this and where in the gemara is it written?

Comment: Towards the beginning of sotah

Answer (score 10):

It is a a baraita in [Masekhet Shabbat 105b](http://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.105b.37?lang=he&layout=block&sidebarLang=all):

> המקרע בגדיו בחמתו והמשבר כליו בחמתו והמפזר מעותיו בחמתו יהא בעיניך כעובד ע"ז
>   שכך אומנתו של יצה"ר היום אומר לו עשה כך ולמחר אומר לו עשה כך
>
> "If one tears his garment in his anger, breaks his utensils in his
>   anger or scatters his money in his anger, he should be in your eyes as
>   one who is performing idolatry. For thus is the craft of the evil inclination: today it tells him "do this", and the next day it tells him "do this" until it tells him "perform idolatry" and he goes and performs it".

Comment: thank you very much, this is exactly what im looking for.